# How to have div extend past a compass susy grid?

Tags: css, layout, compass-sass, susy-compass

I have many elements where the CONTENT of a div should align with my 960 grid, but I'd like the CONTAINER that holds them to extend into the gutter on either side of the grid.

For example, please see following image. I'd like to specify the size of the div with the thing gray line as my grid with, but have that 5-10px of white extend outside.  Is that possible?

[image]

Comment: You may have already thought of this, but your grid container is essentially inside of another container. I'd suggest reflecting that in your markup and setting the padding on the outer container vs. trying to expand the grid dimensions.

Comment: Actually, the BLEED option does this fine.  Make sure you remove the box model option for the container, if you applied it.